# How do I get my Filters from Filtersfeature

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am using `FiltersFeature`:

```
this.features = {
    ftype: 'filters',
    encode: false,
    local: true
};
```

I would like to access my current filters on my table. Ie. not the filter configuration object, but what the changes user has done to the table (I want to save this in the database).

There is a filters object on grid, but that just gives me the filter configuration from all the columns.

```
handler: function (btn) {
    var grid = btn.up('grid');
    grid.filters
}
```

I need the actual values. I'm looking for something like this:

```
var v = {
    filter: {
        column: 'name',
        value: 'bob'
    },
    filter: {
        column: 'date',
        value1: '11.11.11',
        value2: '12.12.12'
    }
}
```

Anyone know where i can get this info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer I found out was to use this method :)

```
myTableGrid.filters.getFilterData()
```

I get something like this :

```
v = [{
        "field": "myColumn1", 
        "data": {
                "type": "string", 
                "value": "anna"}
    }, {
        "field": "myColumn2_fixedvalue",
        "data": {
            "type": "list", 
            "value": [60]}
    }]
```

Comment: Watkin How can You get hold of the value which you enter in filter. Here you placing the value, what if you need to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Filter does not contain any values.
You should parse actual values from the grid.

```
        var columnTitle = [];
        var fieldName = [];
        var data = [];

        var visibleColumns = grid.query('gridcolumn:not([hidden])');
        visibleColumns.forEach(function(c) {           
           columnTitle.push(c.text);
           fieldName.push(c.dataIndex);           
        });

        for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < grid.store.getCount(); rowIndex++) {          
            var row = grid.getView().getRow(rowIndex);
            var fieldValues = Ext.fly(row).query('div.x-grid-cell-inner');
            var map = {}
            for (colIndex = 0; colIndex < fieldName.length; colIndex++) {               
                map[fieldName[colIndex]] = fieldValues[colIndex].textContent;
            }           
            data.push(map);
        }
```

As a result, you will get an array of objects, something like

```
[{"user.login":"iivanov","email":"ivanov@mail.com"},{"user.login":"ppetrov","email":"petrov@mail.com"},{"user.login":"plosev","email":"elk@gmail.com"}]
```

Comment: but i need the filter values that I have used on my filter. Not the actual values in the cells.